# Facebook Query Language gives just user ids

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to print friends of user who uses my application.Using Facebook Query Language(FLQ) to do it. But query gives just user id's.How can i get usernames with profile pictures

Here is my code:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ($session) {
try {
$some_friends = $facebook->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$facebook->getUser().' LIMIT 10'
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
}
}
print_r($some_friends);
```

Here is the result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [uid2] => 521117187 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [uid2] => 526583873 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [uid2] => 527579769 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [uid2] => 531219912 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [uid2] => 533654770 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [uid2] => 539141589 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [uid2] => 539243220 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [uid2] => 539342366 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [uid2] => 549294033 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [uid2] => 557508969 )
     )
```

---

solved...

Answer (score 1):

you can get their picture by posting uid to

http://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture

example
http://graph.facebook.com/557508969/picture

[image]

also his name by getting 
http://graph.facebook.com/557508969/ (JSON encoded)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to change your select query to

```
SELECT id,username,profile_pic FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$facebook->getUser().' LIMIT 10'
```

if i understood your question.

Comment: The friend table only contains the fields uid1 and uid2, and the results of an FQL query can only come from a single table at a time.  So the query on the friend table needs to take place in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

FQL Subqueries are what you need to be using, as the friend table doesn't contain any more information on the users. Try this:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
if ($session) {
try {
$some_friends = $facebook->api(array(
      'method' => 'fql.query',
      'query' => 'SELECT uid,name,picture FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$facebook->getUser().') LIMIT 10'
    ));
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
}
}
print_r($some_friends);
```

Comment: can you write the code with permission please,i think it's about permission.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to request permissions in the PHP SDK - I'm more a JavaScript SDK developer...

Comment: i solved the problem,can you check my question again please ?